# Symfony 1.4 project in SAAS mode - multiple databases

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a Symfony 1.4 project that I want to use in SAAS mode for multiple customers.
The idea is to have multiple domains and databases but to always use the same code. I also don't want to have to change anything in my project for each new customer : everything must be dynamic.

I've been trying for a few hours now to override the database.yml configuration but it wasn't really a success. I added at the beginning of my ProjectConfiguration.class.php :

```
require_once '/path/to/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine.php';
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if(preg_match("#\.saas-domain\.com$#", $serverName))
  $dbname = "db-" . preg_replace("#\.saas-domain\.com$#", "", $serverName);
else
  $dbname = "db-default";

$dsn      = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=localhost";
$user     = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpsw';

try {
  $dbh  = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Can't find that database");
}
```

I tried to put this code at the end of the `setup()` method, same thing : it doesn't seem to be used.

As you can see I wanted to deduce the database to use from the domain (ServerName in apache).

My very last option is to manually alter each `config_database.yml.php` file generated in cache (in fact only alter one and use symlinks), but I really would like not to have to do this.

So my questions are :

- Is it possible to override the database.yml configuration ?
- If not, is there a way I can delete this file or ignore it and set up a manual doctrine configuration ?
- Are there any other solutions that I didn't consider ?

---

**EDIT**

I managed to come up with a solution (with the help of [this article](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippets/tagged/propel+connection/order_by/date)). It's probably not the best way to do it, but at least the result is OK.
The idea is to use Symfony's filters in order to replace the connection created by the database YAML file :

In `config/filters.yml` add the following :

```
myDBConnectionFilter:
  class: myDBConnectionFilter
```

Then create this `myDBConnectionFilter` class and put it anywhere it can be found by Symfony's autoloader (`lib` in most cases). Below is an example of code you can use in this class :

```
<?php

class myDBConnectionFilter extends sfFilter
{
    public function execute($filterChain){
        if ($this->isFirstCall())
        {
            $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
            if(preg_match("#\.saas-domain\.com$#", $serverName))
              $dbname = "db-" . preg_replace("#\.saas-domain\.com$#", "", $serverName);
            else
              $dbname = "db-default";

            $dsn      = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=localhost";
            $user     = 'user';
            $password = 'password';

            $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

            try {
              $default = $manager->getConnection('dbconnection');
              Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->closeConnection($default);

              $dbh  = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
              $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh, 'dbconnection');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $filterChain->execute();
    }
}
```

You'll then need to clear Symfony's cache.

This code retrieve a connection from Doctrine_Manager, close it, then create a new one with the same name to replace it. In this case, the connection is called `dbconnection`. The name of the connection is the one used in database.yml.

As I said, it is not the best way to do it as this method makes two connections to the database instead of one. So if anyone has a better solution i would take it !

Comment: Maybe you could write an installation script which will guess the db name and write it in the `databases.yml` file.

Comment: Have you checked that given the subdomain you're coming from, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is filled accordingly?

Is any PDOException raised once trying to connect to the desired database then?